# testing zend with phpunit gives me "The mysql driver is not currently installed"

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

i have this testing class

```
<?php

class IndexControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase
{
....


    public function testValidLoginShouldGoToProfilePage()
    {
        $this->request->setMethod('POST')
              ->setPost(array(
                  'email' => 'capoarea',
                  'password' => '123456'
              ));
        $this->dispatch('/user/login');
        $this->assertRedirectTo('/index/index');

        $this->resetRequest()
             ->resetResponse();

        $this->request->setMethod('GET')
             ->setPost(array());
        $this->dispatch('/cliente/index');
        $this->assertRoute('default');
        $this->assertModule('default');
        $this->assertController('cliente');
        $this->assertAction('index');
        $this->assertNotRedirect();
    }

}
```

and this application.ini

```
[production]
.....
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "gestionale"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Gestionale_";serve per caricare il plugin di sotto quando si usa anche ZFdebug
resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "Gestionale_Controller_Plugin_Acl"
resources.db.params.profiler = true


....
[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

and i get this error [image]

in application ini *testing* extends *production* so it should have all db config, what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your php command line interpreter uses a different `php.ini` file.

To check for MySQL driver open a new shell prompt and run `php -m` and check that mysql extensions are loaded.

```
> php -m | grep -i sql
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
SQLite
sqlite3
```

To see what ini file is loaded use the `-i` flag of php command

```
> php -i | grep ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/local/etc/php5
Loaded Configuration File => /opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /opt/local/var/db/php5
Additional .ini files parsed => /opt/local/var/db/php5/apc.ini,
```

Don't know if on windows there is a `grep` like command to filter the output, if not you have to examine all the output of both `php -m` and `php -i` to gather the required lines or install a [windows grep](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=windows%20grep) utility

Comment: my php was loading no .ini because EasyPhp is all messed up, i fixed it now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

PHPUnit uses the php.ini for Commandline. I think you have to enable the SQL Drivers there. You can check the path to your php.ini with (tested on OsX :-) )

```
php --ini
```

**result:**

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.2
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.2/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Comment: sorry (at least on windows) php -v types the version, php -m types loaded modules