# How to setup PHPUnit 3.5.15 and Zend framework 1.11.10?

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, phpunit

After spending 1 good day I still unable to resolve the following error:

> Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no
>   testing actions will be created.

This error appears when I create a new Zend-project.

What i have tried so far:

1. Updated Pear to the latest version.
2. changed config to autodiscover as described on the readme of phpunit.
3. Also I changed the include path of my php.ini file to the following:

> include_path=".;S:\PHP\PEAR;S:\PHP\PEAR\PHPUnit;S:\Framework\ZendFramework-1.11.10\library;S:\PHP\PEAR\PEAR"

However I am still receiving the error.

What does work is the commandline phpunit , the correct php.ini is loaded (checked by phpinfo()) so what am I missing?

**Additional information**

```
C:\Users\Dev\Desktop>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         S:\PHP\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Instalation information:

- Apache 2.2.19
- php 5.3.6
- mysql 5.5.15

I did not install xammp or wammp just manual install to learn.

php.ini that load :=> http://pastebin.com/bpqKhF7U

### *Update!*

Php include_path is ambiguous the error you receive is because your .zf.ini is wrongly configured (mine was)

.zf.ini can be found @ users home folder

It looks like this:

> php.include_path=".;S:\xampp\php\;S:\xampp\php\PEAR;S:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit"

After changing this parameter to the right locations the error did not occur anymore!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP command line interpreter in windows can use a different `php.ini` file, see my answer to this question [testing zend with phpunit gives me "The mysql driver is not currently installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245160/testing-zend-with-phpunit-gives-me-the-mysql-driver-is-not-currently-installed/7253978#7253978)

You should check that the `phpunit` is available on your path, what happen if you type `phpunit` in a command prompt? Is phpunit in your path?

Anyway the best method to [install PHPUnit is the pear method](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html), it should take care of any aspect. I always used that method (Linux and Mac) and everything worked with no need to change the path nor the `php.ini` file. Don't know if this is also true for Windows.

**Update**

There is more than one way to change the loaded ini file see all of them [here](http://it.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)

The easiest way could be with an environment variable:

```
PHPRC=path of your current apache php.ini file
```

or with a registry setting

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP], value of IniFilePath (Windows only)
```

In this way you should be able to load the same file for the apache version. Or you can keep CLI configuration separated and replicate your `include_path` setting in `S:\PHP\php.ini`

Comment: I did install phpunit using pear, after reading on the link you provided I used the command php --ini and posted the result of the command prompt output. How do you change the configuration file path?

Comment: You should provide more details in your question, such as - what webserver are you using - kind of installation (for apache WAMP, XAMP or package) - which php.ini file is read from the webserver. Then we can help you.